# GCC is not finding the built-in 'memcpy'

Tags: c, gcc, built-in, cortex-m

I am doing work on an ARM [Cortex-M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M) microcontroller using the *arm-none-eabi* version of GCC. I am also using `-fnostdlib` and `-fnostdin`.

In my code I am using `memcpy` and `strlen`. Both of these functions are built-in functions as per the GCC manual. When I use these function as is or as `__buitin_...`, I get `undefined reference to ...`.

Why is GCC not generating the code as expected?

Comment: These are parts of the standard library, even though they might be implemented as built-in.

Comment: Builtin doesn't mean always inlined. The __builtin_memcpy builtin generates either inline code or a call to memcpy depending on context.

Comment: A little trick: you can create an alternative to memcpy by wrapping whatever you need to copy in a struct, then use the assignment operator to copy the struct by value. This should work regardless of stdlib.h.

Comment: @Lundin not very usable with `strlen`

Comment: @Lundin: It only works up to a certain size and then the compiler inserts a call to -- you guessed it -- *memcpy*. See https://godbolt.org/z/rWzdb3

Comment: @Codo generally it actually does not work at all https://godbolt.org/z/bohrcT your example makes structs aligned.

Comment: Paraphrasing error messages is rarely useful, especially when you remove the most important part (the name of the symbol that is not defined).  Please post the complete (simplified) code and the complete error message next time.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I do understand what is not defined. The `...` part

Comment: @Codo It isn't a universal trick. But the compiler isn't _forced_ to call memcpy, that's an internal call that gcc in this case decided to do. Generally you should ensure that the data is aligned and that the structs may not alias each other (overlapping memory regions). If the compiler can't deduct if the structs overlap or not, it will optimize poorly.

Answer (score 1):

builtins are not real functions. Compiler is free to replace them with the "normal" function call. ARM b as in this example:

```
void *m(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    return __builtin_memcpy(a,b,size);
}

void *m1(void *a, void *b)
{
    return __builtin_memcpy(a,b,16);
}

void *m2(void *a, void *b)
{
    return __builtin_memcpy(a,b,200);
}


volatile int a[1000],b[10000], c[1000];


int main(void)
{
    m((void *)a,(void *)b,16);
    __asm(":::m");
    m((void *)a,(void *)c,400);
}
```

The resulting code will depend on the ARM architecture (if not aligned accesses are legal).

```
CORTEX-M4                                            CORTEX-M0
m:                                                   m:
  b memcpy                                                   push    {r4, lr}
m1:                                                          bl      memcpy
  push {r4, r5}                                              pop     {r4, pc}
  ldr r5, [r1] @ unaligned                           m1:
  ldr r4, [r1, #4] @ unaligned                               push    {r4, lr}
  ldr r2, [r1, #8] @ unaligned                               movs    r2, #16
  ldr r1, [r1, #12] @ unaligned                              bl      memcpy
  str r1, [r0, #12] @ unaligned                              pop     {r4, pc}
  str r5, [r0] @ unaligned                           m2:
  str r4, [r0, #4] @ unaligned                               push    {r4, lr}
  str r2, [r0, #8] @ unaligned                               movs    r2, #200
  pop {r4, r5}                                               bl      memcpy
  bx lr                                                      pop     {r4, pc}
m2:                                                  main:
  movs r2, #200                                              ldr     r0, .L6
  b memcpy                                                   push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
main:                                                        movs    r2, r0
  push {r4, lr}                                              ldr     r3, .L6+4
  ldr r3, .L8                                                ldmia   r3!, {r1, r4, r5}
  ldr r4, .L8+4                                              stmia   r2!, {r1, r4, r5}
  ldm r3, {r0, r1, r2, r3}                                   ldr     r3, [r3]
  stm r4, {r0, r1, r2, r3}                                   str     r3, [r2]
  :::m                                                       :::m
  mov r2, #400                                               movs    r2, #200
  mov r0, r4                                                 ldr     r1, .L6+8
  ldr r1, .L8+8                                              lsls    r2, r2, #1
  bl memcpy                                                  bl      memcpy
  movs r0, #0                                                movs    r0, #0
  pop {r4, pc}                                               pop     {r4, r5, r6, pc}
.L8:                                                 .L6:
  .word b                                                    .word   a
  .word a                                                    .word   b
  .word c                                                    .word   c
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fh68cv

Comment: This is very interesting. Looks like code generation is only for small memcpys. I was hoping that gcc would help me with efficient memcpy for large copies.

Comment: memcpy from the standard library is very efficient. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Shouldn't the real question be: how can the standard library's *memcpy* be used without dragging in unnecessary weight?

Comment: @Codo use nano one and there is no additional weight. I do not see any point of not using standard library

Comment: At the moment this my project is a vanity project. The main goal is learning by writing all code from scratch. A naive memcpy will do for now but I might play with an implementation using ldm